How can I use Google Cloud Storage and Local folders together using Django?
I have a Django app with images stored on Google Cloud Storage, but I need to serve a single image from the local filesystem. Here is my current setup:
Settings.py:
GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(credentials_dict)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
GS_PROJECT_ID = 'projectid'
GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucketname'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'

HTML:
<img src="{% static 'img/testimg.png' %}" alt="">

When I tried removing the STATICFILES_STORAGE line, Django searched for all images in the local folders instead of just the one I needed.
How can I configure Django to search for only one specific image locally while keeping the rest on Google Cloud Storage?

It's not clear what you mean by "I want to search just for one image".  Certainly if you know the path of the image you want, then just use that path.  If you don't know the path, then you can't get the image.  What is the problem you're running into with that? Please edit the question to explain the problem in more detail, and show what you tried that doesn't work the way you expect.

I know the path of the image, it's "static/img/testimg.png", but if I use the relative path the image doesn't work. It works just when I remove the STATICFILES_STORAGE config and use {% static %} tag
